# Error in running 'npm install' after creating an express app

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I ran: `npm install npm install -g express-generator`
->  `express <name>` -> `npm install` which gave me this error:

```
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated constantinople@3.0.2: Please update to at least constantinople 3.1.1
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path <path>
npm ERR! dest <path>
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '<path>' -> '<path>'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '<path>' -> '<path>'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '<path>' -> '<path>'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!     path: '<path>',
npm ERR!     dest: '<path>'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   dest: '<path>',
npm ERR!   parent: '<name>'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

package-lock.json has been created. Is this an error to worry about? If yes how to solve this issue? I did `npm install pug --save` which too gave me `4 vulnerabilities (3 low, 1 critical)`
. But when I created an express app using express name, it scaffold out a views folder with files such as: 'error.jade', etc. Now after installing 'pug', do I need to change something else in my files too, since those initial codes were default in the app created by latest express-generator?

Comment: As you might see, you deprecated package that your trying to install, Jade is not longer exists

Comment: Okay, I did. But when I created an express app using `express name`, it scaffold out a views folder with files such as: 'error.jade', etc. Now after installing 'pug', do I need to change something else in my files too, since those initial codes were default in the app created by latest express-generator?